# How do I map two domains to the same wordpress installation?

Tags: customization, links

I originally have the website working with: (example) www.domainoriginal.com

But I want to have another domain (www.domainsecond.com) also use the same Wordpress installation.

I have changed the A record in the DNS configuration so www.domainsecond.com points to the correct IP Address but all the links are still in the old form.

When I click "About", it goes to www.domainoriginal.com/about but I want it to stay as www.domainsecond.com/about and display the same page. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this without some technical intervention. Basically, WordPress uses the site name that you provide in your WordPress Settings (and is saved to the database) to generate the links for your website.

Here is what I just thought of:

1. Create a plugin to solve this problem.
2. The plugin will detect the referral site.
3. you add a hook to the "home_url" filter to change your site url just for the current session

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add this to your wp-config after table prefix.

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

See reference to this [here](http://myjeeva.com/mapping-multiple-domains-into-single-instance-of-wordpress.html).